# htaccess SetEnvIf variable increment

Tags: apache, .htaccess, environment-variables, increment, setenv

it's possible to increment environment variables in htaccess (example: to count failed logins or access)?

Something like:

```
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MYVAR:MYVAR+1]
```

or

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "\.gif$" MYVAR=MYVAR+1
```

Tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer:** No you cannot do that in `.htaccess` alone. It is not a scripting language where you can do maths operations. You will need to do that in your server side scripts.